# Libreoffice calc relative and absolute cell reference on copy-paste

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I'd like to create a simple Calc sheet, where column A contains the days, B contains how many hours of work i had done and C the price for that day. The price is simply a multiplication of hours (B col.) and a predefined price. But the price per hour may change, so I'd like this to be in a cell too, and the daily price formula for C3 could be **=B3*A30** where A30 is the price per hour. But if i copy the C3 cell to C4, C5, ... the A30 cell reference moves down too, to A31, A32..., just like the B3 moves down to B4, B5...

**How can I make a cell reference fixed, while the other relative when copy-pasting cell in Libreoffice Calc?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution: the formula in column C should be like this:

(C3 cell) **=B3*$A$30**

This way, on copy-paste only the B3 reference is rewritten, the A30 is left unchanged. The $A$30 syntax can be achieved with Shift+F4 too.

Comment: Thank you for returning to answer your own question, this solved my problem.

Comment: Also using `Shift`+`F4` multiple times will cycle through the variations of absolute rows&cols OR rows OR cols. I was unable to paste cell to other cells in opencalc, can now.